# Nodejs - Redis GET return NULL

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, redis, backend

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const index = require('../../../index');

//get caching data in redis
const redisGet = async(key) => {
    const getAsync = promisify(index.clientRedis.get).bind(index.clientRedis);            
    const value = await getAsync(key);

    return value;
}

module.exports = redisGet;
```

My "redisGet" function return right value at the first time, and later times, it only return "null" although the caching data is still exist.

```
const cachingData = await redisGet('key');//first time: cachingData = <right value>//later times: cachingData = null
```

How can I fix it ?

Hope for solutions. Thanks all !

Answer (score 0):

You might be storing the key with a TTL value.

After the TTL is up the key is expired and null is returned if you try to fetch the key.

ref: https://redis.io/commands/expire/

Comment: You should summarise what the link point to if you can in case it breaks

Comment: @moken we can always use the archived version of pages that break, here: https://web.archive.org/web/20221229220902/https://redis.io/commands/expire/